# Importing users from spreadsheet to list

Tags: list, spreadsheet, excel-import

I have an Excel spreadsheet with information I need to import to a list. The issue is that the spreadsheet includes a column of names I have to add to a column which comprises of users in my organization. I am using "Importing from CSV", and it does not recognize any of the names as users. How can I get this done without having to add 1000+ user names manually? The end result has to be a column of names and not just plain text....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import users from an excel spreadsheet.  The catch is, just like with any Excel-to-list connection, you need to make sure the data your are loading from Excel into SharePoint matches the data type and input SharePoint is expecting.  The Person/Group field used by SharePoint will not accept the Display name of the user.  SharePoint is expecting the UserID from their UPS.  The best way to see how SharePoint expects any Excel data loaded, make a list with each data type, put some data in each field, and export it with a connection.

In short, yes you can, but you need to make sure your data you have in your Excel is what SharePoint expects.

Answer (score 1):

You can't from just the "Import from Spreadsheet". You'll have to write a powershell script that will push a data into a list programmatically whilst finding the correct user.

This technet article explains how to: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18830.sharepoint-2010-import-data-from-excel-into-a-list-using-powershell.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When I copy names from Excel to SharePoint, it’s always a manual process.  Name data copied from Excel to SharePoint's People and Group column type must match AD information exactly or you will receive an error in SharePoint after you either import or copy/paste in Quick Edit.  To speed things up, I use Excel’s Find/Replace function.  I open Outlook on one monitor and Excel in a second monitor.  I then search for a user in Outlook and copy their display name, and then in Excel I use the Find/Replace feature.  In the Find What box I enter the name as it appears in the workbook and in the Replace With box I enter the copied display name from Outlook.